# Can you get animationend to fire when changing style attribute?

Tags: css, css-animations

It's not firing in this example:

http://codepen.io/loren/pen/QbeyEy

```
<div id='slider'></slider>

#slider
  width 100px
  height 50px
  background-color black
  transition transform 300ms 

$slider = $('#slider')

$slider.one 'animationend', ->
  alert 'ended'

setTimeout ->
  $slider.css 
    transform: 'translate(100px,0px)'
, 1000
```

Comment: What you posted is not javascript :p

Comment: Firing?? I see the black rectangle moving...

Comment: Are you in need of CSS flames?

Answer (score 1):

The correct event is `transitionend`, not `animationend`.